# Azure Cloud Service Instance Keep Recycling after deployment - SDK 2.6

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, wcf, azure

I have ASP.NET MVC 5 project, referenced a SOAP Service from one of our client. I added the service using Visual Studio and, it requires a username/password authentication.

Here is the configuration part for the SOAP reference from the Web.Config file.

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="SoapBinding">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="65536" maxArrayLength="16384" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
          <security mode="None">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" realm="" />
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="*** SOAP URL ***" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="SoapBinding" contract="** ContactName**" name="name1">
        <headers>
          <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
            <wsse:UsernameToken>
              <wsse:Username>** username**</wsse:Username>
              <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">** password**</wsse:Password>
            </wsse:UsernameToken>
          </wsse:Security>
        </headers>
      </endpoint>
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Then, I created Azure Cloud Project, and publish the project from Visual Studio, but unfortunately the Instance is keep recycling.

The moment, I remove the `<System.ServiceModel>`, and remove the SOAP reference and redeploy; the web application works fine.

The MVC project run perfectly on local referencing the SOAP service, and I am able to communicate with the SOAP service.

**Note**: I have RDC to the azure instance and browse the application from IIS, I can see the page is loading and result are displaying from the SOAP service, but the Instance is keep recycling on Azure dashboard; therefore it won't be accessed from outside.

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Try preparing the package and looking inside - maybe some dependencies are missing.